# Drop a database using entity framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to remove a database form my application using entity framework.
The code I use is the following:

```
using (var dbContext = container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>())
    {
      dbContext.Database.Delete();
    }
```

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.delete(v=vs.113).aspx) this should work but nothing happens.

the dbContext is registered using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` and should be the same instance used to create the DB.

Answer (score 3):

Adding, updating and deleting instances of entity types needs   `dbContext.SaveChanges()` to reflect changes.

However  `dbContext.Database.Delete()` does not need `dbContext.SaveChanges()`.

If you open connection for example from Sql Management Studio to your database and try to `dbContext.Database.Delete()` then you receive `Cannot drop database "dbContext" because it is currently in use.` If you restart you sql server, you drop those connections and then retry `dbContext.Database.Delete()` you successfully drop database.

Last thing is  **refresh  database list** in Sql Management Studio in order to see that database is not there any more.

Testing with this code snippet:

```
using (var dbContext = new dbContext())
{
    dbContext.Database.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Try with using `using (var dbContext =  new ApplicationDbContext())`

Comment: Tied it but to no avail. DB is still there.

Comment: @memoryofadream I tested issue on my machine, see update, hope this time it works for you

Comment: Sorry for the long gap. I've been working on other stuff lately
I believe I now understand the problem.
The database is still being used by the current application, that's why I can't delete it. Seems like a chicken and egg problem.
I've tried disposing the db context entirely and creating a new one, but didn't work.
I'd like to remove the DB from the same process that created it and without having to restart sql. Otherwise I can delete it manually after the application closes without difficulty.

Comment: It is getting interesting. I did not try create and delete from application. As you report and from my attemps, operation can only be done with existing database...

Answer (score 1):

After @moguzalp and this ([MSDN Database.Delete Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.delete(v=vs.113).aspx)), I came with a solution for my case:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

Database.Delete("connectionStringOrName");
```

In my case I was trying to Recreate a mssqllocalDb database for test purposes. But whenever I used the same DbContext (or an immediately new one, disposing the first and opening another), it looked like the database was still up when I tried to create it.

Bad Example: (x)

```
public static void RecreateDatabase(string schemaScript)
{   
    using (DbContext context = new DbContext("connectionStringName"))
    {
        context.Database.Delete(); // Delete returns true, but...
        Database database = context.Database;
        database.Create(); // Database already exists!
        database.ExecuteSqlCommand(schemaScript);
    }
}
```

Working example: (/)

```
public static void RecreateDatabase(string schemaScript)
{   
    Database.Delete(); // Opens and disposes its own connection

    using (DbContext context = new DbContext("connectionStringName")) // New connection
    {
        Database database = context.Database;
        database.Create(); // Works!
        database.ExecuteSqlCommand(schemaScript);
    }
}
```

Context: I'm using this on an [AssemblyInitialize] function to test my ModelContexts

Answer (score 0):

All of your changes occurred on local variable `dbcontext`.

That is final kick > add `dbContext.SaveChanges();` at the end of your using block like so:

```
 using (var dbContext = container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>())
{
  dbContext.Database.Delete();
  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```